# How to make Pause function to synchronous countdown timers?

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

Below code is for 3 synchronous countdown timers, each timer runs its function when time is up. Start and Stop functions work well, but now I need to add "Pause" button to freeze time counter then when I press "Start" again the timers resume. I added pause_flag variable which equals to zero and added in Start function while(pause_flag==0) it counts down and in Pause function, (pause_flag==1) so when I press "Pause", it should freeze counter, but it doesn't work, the whole program stop (no response)

```
import time
from tkinter import *

def first():  
   print("first new time is up \n") 
   #stop module (1)

def second():  
   print("second new time is up \n")  
   #stop module (2)

def third():  
   print("third new time is up \n")  
   #stop module (3)
   
#Create interface#
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600")
root.title("Countdown Timer")

def modules():
    if (clockTime[0] == 0):
        first()
    if(clockTime[1] == 0):
        second()
    if(clockTime[2] == 0):
        third()

#initialize timers lists
timers_number = 3
hrString=[0]*timers_number
minString=[0]*timers_number
secString=[0]*timers_number

totalSeconds  = [0]*timers_number
totalMinutes = [0]*timers_number
totalHours = [0]*timers_number

for i in range(timers_number):
    hrString[i] = StringVar()
    hrString[i].set("00")

for i in range(timers_number):
    minString[i] = StringVar()
    minString[i].set("00")
    
for i in range(timers_number):
    secString[i] = StringVar()
    secString[i].set("00")
#initialze list of each timer with zero seconds to store timers in seconds   
clockTime = [0]*timers_number
   
#Get User Input
hourTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""),textvariable=hrString[0]).place(x=170, y=100) 
minuteTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""),textvariable=minString[0]).place(x=220, y=100)  
secondTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""),textvariable=secString[0]).place(x=270, y=100) 

hourTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=hrString[1]).place(x=170, y=180) 
minuteTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=minString[1]).place(x=220, y=180)  
secondTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=secString[1]).place(x=270, y=180) 

hourTextBox3 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=hrString[2]).place(x=170, y=260) 
minuteTextBox3 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=minString[2]).place(x=220, y=260)  
secondTextBox3 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=secString[2]).place(x=270, y=260) 

pause_flag = 0

def start():
    try:
        for i in range (timers_number):
            clockTime[i] = int(hrString[i].get())*3600 + int(minString[i].get())*60 + int(secString[i].get()) 
    except:
        print("Incorrect values")
        
    while (clockTime[0] > -1 or clockTime[1] > -1 or clockTime[2] > -1):
        
        for i in range(timers_number):
            
            if(clockTime[i] > -1):
                totalMinutes[i], totalSeconds[i] = divmod(clockTime[i], 60)
                if(totalMinutes[i]>60):
                    totalHours[i], totalMinutes[i] = divmod(totalMinutes[i], 60)
                
                hrString[i].set("{0:2d}".format(totalHours[i]))
                minString[i].set("{0:2d}".format(totalMinutes[i]))
                secString[i].set("{0:2d}".format(totalSeconds[i]))
                
                #time expires 
            if(clockTime[i] == 0):
                hrString[i].set("00")
                minString[i].set("00")
                secString[i].set("00")
        
        for i in range(timers_number):
            if(clockTime[i] == 0):
                modules()
                        
            #while (pause_flag == 0):
            clockTime[i] -= 1
        time.sleep(1)    
        root.update()
           
def stop():
    for i in range (timers_number):
        clockTime[i] = 0
          
def pause():
    if pause_flag == 0:
        pause_flag = 1
    first()
    second()
    third()
          
setTimeButton = Button(root, text='START', bd='5', command=start).place(x=200, y=500)       
setTimeButton = Button(root, text='STOP', bd='5', command=stop).place(x=350, y=500)   
setTimeButton = Button(root, text='PAUSE', bd='5', command=pause).place(x=500, y=500)   
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe `command=pause` instead of `command=start` in the PAUSE button ?

Comment: Rectified to be pause, but still doesn't work. actually putting while loop with pause_flag = 0 doesn't even allow Start button to work

Comment: Use the `after` function instead of loops.

Comment: I tried .after but doesn't work with multiple timers, would you please share if you have multiple countdown timer same start and Entries are updated while counting

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from tkinter import *

def first():  
   print("first new time is up \n") 
   #stop module (1)

def second():  
   print("second new time is up \n")  
   #stop module (2)

def third():  
   print("third new time is up \n")  
   #stop module (3)
   
#Create interface#
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600")
root.title("Countdown Timer")

def modules():
    if (clockTime[0] == 0 or clockTime[0] == -1):
        first()
    if(clockTime[1] == 0 or clockTime[1] == -1):
        second()
    if(clockTime[2] == 0 or clockTime[2] == -1):
        third()

#initialize timers lists
timers_number = 3
hrString=[0]*timers_number
minString=[0]*timers_number
secString=[0]*timers_number

totalSeconds  = [0]*timers_number
totalMinutes = [0]*timers_number
totalHours = [0]*timers_number

for i in range(timers_number):
    hrString[i] = StringVar()
    hrString[i].set("00")

for i in range(timers_number):
    minString[i] = StringVar()
    minString[i].set("00")
    
for i in range(timers_number):
    secString[i] = StringVar()
    secString[i].set("00")

   
#Get User Input
hourTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""),textvariable=hrString[0]).place(x=170, y=100) 
minuteTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""),textvariable=minString[0]).place(x=220, y=100)  
secondTextBox1 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""),textvariable=secString[0]).place(x=270, y=100) 

hourTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=hrString[1]).place(x=170, y=180) 
minuteTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=minString[1]).place(x=220, y=180)  
secondTextBox2 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=secString[1]).place(x=270, y=180) 

hourTextBox3 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=hrString[2]).place(x=170, y=260) 
minuteTextBox3 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=minString[2]).place(x=220, y=260)  
secondTextBox3 = Entry(root, width=3, font=("Calibri", 20, ""), textvariable=secString[2]).place(x=270, y=260) 



def countdown():

    for i in range (timers_number):
           
        if(clockTime[i] > -1):
            totalMinutes[i], totalSeconds[i] = divmod(clockTime[i], 60)
            if(totalMinutes[i]>60):
                totalHours[i], totalMinutes[i] = divmod(totalMinutes[i], 60)
            
            hrString[i].set("{0:2d}".format(totalHours[i]))
            minString[i].set("{0:2d}".format(totalMinutes[i]))
            secString[i].set("{0:2d}".format(totalSeconds[i]))
           
        if(clockTime[i] == 0):       #time is up
            hrString[i].set("00")
            minString[i].set("00")
            secString[i].set("00")
            modules()            
        
        if(clockTime[i] != -1):    #timer is paused
            clockTime[i] -= 1     
    
    if(clockTime[i] != -1):
        root.after(1000, countdown)   
    
                     
def starttimer():
    #initialze list of each timer with zero seconds to store timers in seconds   
    global clockTime
    clockTime = [0]*timers_number
    try:
        #global clockTime
        for i in range (timers_number):
            clockTime[i] = int(hrString[i].get())*3600 + int(minString[i].get())*60 + int(secString[i].get()) 
    except:
        print("Incorrect values")
    
    countdown()
    
     
def stop():
    for i in range (timers_number):
        clockTime[i] = 0
          
def pause():
    for i in range (timers_number):
        clockTime[i] = -1
    modules()
 

def GUI():
             
    setTimeButton = Button(root, text='START', bd='5', command=starttimer).place(x=200, y=500)       
    setTimeButton = Button(root, text='STOP', bd='5', command=stop).place(x=350, y=500)   
    setTimeButton = Button(root, text='PAUSE', bd='5', command=pause).place(x=500, y=500)   
    root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).